# Excel - Find ID-related Value and fill in another workbook

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

I'm working in a small hospital in India having following problem:
For a special drug we're having a list with DATE,ID,DOSE,DURATION,NEXT VISIT which we us as a daily working list (workbook 1), means one ID (person) can show up more than once in this list.

In another workbook we are having a "Master file" (workbook 2) with each ID only once but the pattern (DATE,DURATION, NEXT VISIT) is repeated every time the persons comes again (so DATE2, DURATION2, NEXT VISIT2)

I'm looking for an elegant way to fill the datas from my daily list (workbook 1) automatically in the master sheet (workbook 2). 
Therefore I assume I would need some IF + INDEX/Match + Array function to find the ID in workbook 1, get the values for DATE1, DURATION1, NEXT VISIT2 and fill in to workbook 2, than go further down the list in workbook 1, find the next time the patient came, get the datas and fill it in again in workbook 2, but now in the DATE2... and so on.

I add two pictures the explain the problem.

Daily Sheet:
[image]

Master Sheet: 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. It is possible to find the values with formulae. You'll just need the headers to show numbers, e.g. 1 with the format of *0 "st visit"* etc.
2. Unfortunately the functions will never deal with two things: data loss and overflow. Imagine the patient coming on an 8th occasion and it not showing in your table 'cause you've only filled it to 7.

The function you're probably looking for is

```
=SUMPRODUCT(1*(A3>$A$3:$A$8),1*(B3=$B$3:$B$8))+1
```

which needs to be added to workbook one and will tell you the # of the given meeting, first: 1, second: 2 etc.  A further issue with this formula is that is will not distinguish between two numbers of the same value. If a person happens to visit you twice on one day (assuming you're not recording down to the hours), it will only count as one.

Answer (score 0):

As described in the other answer you can do it with formula but it may not be the best / easiest solution, I'd use one of the below options:

### Pivot table:

Probably the easiest and most elegant solution if you can live with its limitations:
- destination range is not editable (maybe its even a positive in your case).
- you can use only number and date values in the body of your table (only text in your example is rate, but you can set custom number format to show "mg" after the number).
Preparation:
- add a new column in your table - VisitSequence: `=countifs(f:f,f3,b:b,"<="&b3)`.
- create a pivot table. Column labels: ID; row headers: VisitSequence; values: Date, dose, duration, next visit (as you have only one row for each ID X date combination you can use either sum either average).

### VBA:

Requires much more work than pivot but it's far more flexible.

### MS Access:

Native tool for the report you need. It may require some learning from you, but it can be the best long term solution.